# We removed a small feature in our front end code, should I delete or hide this feature, especially since it might be used again in the future?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, hide, hidden

We have a checkbox React element in a filter modal that can either be checked or unchecked. My team decided to remove this specific checkbox's use for now. Now, it ***might*** be used in the future, and we ***do*** have a significant amount of code attached to it. Should we delete all the code for it, or make some sort of "hidden" variable to simply conditionally hide it - especially since it may very well be used again in the future?

Answer (score 0):

In the world of Github, it's better to remove any unused code. It can be brought back from the Github history if and when needed. The only thing we need is to have proper commit messages and branch names.

And if in case it will not be needed or say we get a checkbox which has a completely different look and feel, we will already be having lesser code.